# python check either n of m variable condition matches

Tags: python

There are few methods are written which perform some of the tasks and return the string value.

```
def method1():
  #stuffs
  return string

def method2():
  #stuffs
  return string

def method3():
  #stuffs
  return string 

outm1 = method1()
outm2 = method2()
outm3 = method3()
```

Now I want to perform the condition work to check whether 2 out of 3 above variable string value is same, if so I need to print that value otherwise will print different value.

I am aware that if the methods are returning `True` or `False` then we can do with below way,

```
if sum([outm1 , outm2 , outm3]) >= 2:
  #do stuffs
```

but not sure how to perform with string values...

Comment: You can refer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643850/what-is-a-good-way-to-do-countif-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a good way to do countif in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643850/what-is-a-good-way-to-do-countif-in-python)