# Excel 'COUNTIF() ' functionality using Python Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, excel-formula

How to implement the Excel 'COUNTIF()' using python

Please see the below image for the reference,
I have a column named 'Title' and it contains some text (CD,PDF). And I need  to find the count of the string in the column as given below.

```
No.of CD : 4
No.of PDF: 1
```

By using Excel I could find the same by using the below formula

```
=COUNTIF($A$5:$A$9,"CD")
```

How can I do the same using python.

[image]

Comment: Might [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643850/what-is-a-good-way-to-do-countif-in-python) help?

Comment: Hi, please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly

Comment: df[df['A'] == 'CD'].sum()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can do map to compare with "CD" then sum all the values
Example:
Create "title" data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Title":["CD","CD","CD","PDF","CD"]})
```

The countif using `map` then `sum`

```
df["Title"].map(lambda x: int(x=="CD")).sum()
```

Answer (score 2):

For a simple summary of list item counts, try `.value_counts()` on a Pandas data frame column:

```
my_list = ['CD','CD','CD','PDF','CD']        
df['my_column'] = pd.DataFrame(my_list)    # create data frame column from list
    
df['my_column'].value_counts()
```

[image]

... or on a Pandas series:

```
pd.Series(my_list).value_counts()
```

[image]

Having a column of counts can be especially useful for scrutinizing issues in larger datasets.  Use the `.count()` method to create a column with corresponding counts (similar to using `COUNTIF()` to populate a column in Excel):

[image]

```
df['countif'] = [my_list.count(i) for i in my_list]  # count list item occurrences and assign to new column

display(df[['my_column','countif']])  # view results
```

[image]