# How to find mode in nested array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, nested

I am trying to find the mode of an array then count how many times that number appears in the array. However the way the problem I am trying to solve is set up has nested arrays so the [1] index in each array (the string) is irrelevant. How do I run this code to only apply to the [0] index of all the nested arrays?

```
from statistics import mode

arr = [[1,'cat'][1,'dog'][2,'fish']]
modeNum = mode(arr)
print(arr.count(modeNum))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to find the mode of `[1,1,2]` following your example, you could use a comprehension list such as

`numbers = [x[0] for x in arr]`

Then find the mode with `mode(numbers)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using generators.  The counting line (with `print`) is taken from [What is a good way to do countif in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643850/what-is-a-good-way-to-do-countif-in-python)

```
from statistics import mode

arr = [[1,'cat'][1,'dog'][2,'fish']]
modeNum = mode(x[0] for x in arr)
print(sum(1 for x in arr if x[0] == modeNum))
```

Comment: Would you say the OP's question is a duplicate of the question you linked to?

Comment: The linked question is about counting occurrences of a known value, like "5".  OP also wants to know to find the mode of their list, which is not covered there, but might be somewhere else.