# object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len(): How can I fix this?

Tags: python, list, numpy

I'm trying to calculate the total number of values above 1.6 in my list of 10,000 numbers. I've tried a few ways:

```
for value in chi_sq_values:
    if value > 1.6:
        print(len(value))
```

gives me the error in my title but the following works

```
greater = [i for i in chi_sq_values if i > 1.6]
total = len(greater)
print(total)
```

I want to try two methods to see validate my answer, how can i fix the first one so it works?

Comment: In the first one you are not counting anything. You could do ```np.count_nonzero(chi_sq_values > 1.6)``` to get the count.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a good way to do countif in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643850/what-is-a-good-way-to-do-countif-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first code snippet, you try printing the `len` of `value`. As `numpy.float64` has no len, you get an error.

Therefore, in order to count all values bigger then 1.6, you can simply use a counter:

```
counter = 0
for value in chi_sq_values:
    if value > 1.6:
        counter += 1
print(counter)
```

Answer (score 3):

In your first example, you iterate the items of the list and access directly the value. However, the item doesn't have `len()'. You need to generate the list on your own, in order to evaluate the length.

```
chi_sq_values = [1, 2, 3]
greater = []
for value in chi_sq_values:
    if value > 1.6:
        print(value)
        greater.append(value)

print(len(greater))
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means that an you cannot call `len` on `numpy.float64` object so you need to do this different way.

Assuming that `chi_sq_values` is plain list, here's how to do it fast

```
np.count_nonzero(np.asarray(chi_sq_values) > 1.6)
```